# Clear unread inbox messages

Tags: discussion

I could not find the right area to post this, but I could use some help.

I try to answer all my inbox messages, but it is now impossible.

Is there a way to mark them all as read with just a few clicks?

[image]

Comment: There's "Mark all read" right at the top of the list.

Comment: @muru That did the trick. :-)

Comment: See this announcement on MSE for more info: [Inbox improvements are live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384148/335251)